# Apache Ignite SqlFieldQuery on top of cache storing BinaryObject

Tags: java, distributed-computing, ignite, gridgain

I cannot seem to get this to work, and have scoured the net for documentation or examples to no avail

## Goal

To run a simple aggregation query on an Ignite Cache backed by `BinaryObject` values with `UUID` as the key

## Put Operation Code

```
IgniteBinary binary = ignite.binary();
            IgniteCache<UUID, BinaryObject> rowCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME).withKeepBinary();

            // put

            final int NUM_ROW = 100000;
            final int NUM_COL = 100;
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROW; i++) {
                BinaryObjectBuilder builder = binary.builder(ROW);
                for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COL; j++) {
                    builder.setField("col" + j, Math.random(), Double.class);
                }
                BinaryObject obj = builder.build();
                rowCache.put(UUID.randomUUID(), obj);
            }
```

## Read Operation Code

```
IgniteCache<UUID, BinaryObject> cache = ignite.cache(CACHE_NAME).withKeepBinary();
final SqlFieldsQuery sqlFieldsQuery = new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT COUNT(col1)" + cache.getName());
FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> result = cache.query(sqlFieldsQuery);
```

## Error

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "COL1" not found; SQL statement
```

## EDIT

I've since added a `QueryEntity` to the cache configuration to make the problem disappear

```
 final QueryEntity queryEntity = new QueryEntity();
        queryEntity.setTableName(CACHE_NAME);
        queryEntity.setKeyFieldName("key");
        queryEntity.setKeyType(String.class.getName());
        queryEntity.setValueType(Row.class.getName());
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        fields.put("key", String.class.getName());
        for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++) {
            fields.put("col" + i, Double.class.getName());
        }
        queryEntity.setFields(fields);
        return queryEntity;
```

However, it is unclear to me how `QueryEntity`'s `setValueType` and `setValueFieldName` does? My value type is an arbitrary Binary object with arbitrary key, values

I would like to declare these via `fields.put(<colName>, <colType>);` ...

I am able to get everything to work using POJOs, but not `BinaryObject` as the value type

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT COUNT(col1)" + cache.getName())
```

Cache name is a schema name, and class name (`Row`) is a table name. Looks like you have incorrect table name.

Also make sure that `ROW` in `binary.builder(ROW)` equals to `QueryEntity.valueType`.